# Adding users to Firebase Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm learning Firebase and creating my first project with it.  I'm using FirebaseUI to simplify the authentication.  I'm now working on the database and I need to start by adding my authenticated users to it.  I've read all the documentation and I'm able to do this, but I'm wondering if I'm doing it the best way.

Since I'm  using FirebaseUI and I'm not actually calling the `signIn()` or `createUser()` methods of Firebase Authentication myself, I thought the best way for me to add users would be to do it `onAuthStateChanged()`

```
usersRef = rootRef.child('users')

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    let userRef = usersRef.child(user.uid)
    userRef.set({
      name: user.displayName,
      email: user.email,
      photoURL: user.photoURL,
      emailVerified: user.emailVerified,
    })
  }
}
```

This works fine but I'm concerned about two things:

1)  This sets the user data every time the user is authenticated, even if the user already exists and nothing has changed.  A simple page reload will rewrite the user to the database.

2)  In order for this to work, the userRef location needs to be writable by the user.  This would mean that the `emailVerified` in the userRef location isn't reliable because the user could potentially modify it himself.  I could just rely on the `emailVerified` returned from `onAuthStateChanged` which the user could never modify, but I'm wondering if I'm just doing this wrong or if there's a better way.

A possible solution is described in a video found at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QEd2lEoXpp40.  He creates two sections in the database: `users` and `loginQueue`.  A user in `users` is only readable by the authorized user and `loginQueue` is only writable by an authorized user.  When a user is authenticated, his data gets written to the `loginQueue`.  He then uses the `on()` method to check for a child added to the `loginQueue` that matches their user.uid and somehow uses the `update` method to write to the user data to  `users`.  This works but I don't understand how.  How can is the client able to send an `update()` to `users\uid` if it's only readable?  You can see his code at 7:00 in the video.  This has me stumped.  This works but why.

I just implemented the technique as shown in the video and although it worked for him, I encountered a `PERMISSION_DENIED` error when trying to update the only readable user data.  This is what I thought SHOULD happen but in his video he clearly shows this was not happening.  Unless I'm missing something which I don't think I am, his method doesn't work anymore.  Maybe it was a bug that was later fixed?

UPDATE:  Thanks to Doug Stevenson for pointing me to Firebase Cloud Functions.  I was able to completely solve my problem by creating a cloud function that responds when new users are authenticated.  Here is my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.addUserToDB = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
  admin.database().ref('/users/' + event.data.uid).set({
    name: event.data.displayName,
    email: event.data.email
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common strategy.

1. Authentication shouldn't happen too often.  Also, if nothing changed in user record since the last write, nothing should actually happen.  You don't pay for the bandwidth for client writes to the database.
2. Split your user data up into two sections, one that's writable by the current UID, and the other that's not.  That will prevent problems with users modifying data that you'd not like them to.

Alternately to this, set aside another location in your database where your clients can push commands to update data elsewhere, and use a [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) trigger to read these commands, act on them with elevated privilege, checking for correctness, and delete them.

Comment: 1) Why wouldn't the `set()` write happen?  I never read anything about `set()` not writing if the data is the same.  As far as I understand it, it always writes and overwrites.  Even if it does write when nothing has changed I guess it's not a huge concern, but it had me wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: 2) I watched a video where someone did just that.  When the auth state changed, he saved the user data to a LoginQueue reference and then listened to `child_added` with `on()`.  When it detected a child was added to the LoginQueue, it added the user to the Users reference and removed it from the LoginQueue.  He made the user data only readable and the loginQueue data only writable.  I don't understand how he was able to write to userdata during the `on()` as it was only readable, but it worked.  But even so, the user could still alter the `emailVerified` by just modifying the LoginQueue

Comment: Cloud Functions is much cleaner and lets you isolate sensitive code on the backend, unified among all your types of clients.  I give an overview of this strategy (in the context of a simple web game) here: https://youtu.be/eWj6dxfN63g?t=11m31s

Comment: This has me stumped.  If you go to 7:00 in the video at https://howtofirebase.com/firebase-data-modeling-939585ade7f4 you'll see his rules on the right and his code on the left.  How is it even possible that he is updating the `user` on the `accountsRef` if the data`accountsRef` points to is marked as only readable?

Comment: I'll have to learn about these Cloud Functions you guys are talking about.  Always more to learn!

Comment: Do I need to use Firebase Hosting to use Cloud Functions?  During setup it tells me to use `firebase init` and `firebase deploy` in my project directory.  But I'm not using Firebase Hosting, my site is hosted on my VPS.  I don't want to deploy my entire site.

Comment: Nevermind I see how I can deploy only the functions.  When you go "Set up Functions" on the project panel it made it seem like I had to deploy the whole site.

Comment: These Cloud Functions are great!  Totally solved my problem and made it extremely easy!